# min distance in a triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles

I have two questions that I have no idea where to begin.

1. Given a triangle ABC, find a point M inside the triangle (it can be on the edges) such that AM+BM+CM in minimum.
2. Given a triangle ABC, find a point O inside the triangle (it can be on the edges) such that the sum of the distances of the triangle's edges to the point O in minimum.

Thank You!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: At least for an equilateral triangle, I would have thought any point in the triangle satisfies (2)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point 2. Let edges are $a,b,c$ and distances are $d,e,f$ what you can say about $ad+be+cf$ ?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu yes